# C - The loop doesn't continue

Tags: c, loops

Why doesn't this loop continue after I enter the letter `y` into the `char` answer?

I thought `getchar()` would help but it doesn't seem like its doing anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char answer = 'y';
    int num = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while(answer != 'n')
    {
        int mult = 1;
        int k = 1;
        while (k <= num)
        {
            mult *= k;
            k++;
        }
        printf("%d! = %d\n", num, mult);

        printf("Would you like to try another number? \n");
        printf("Enter: y for yes | n for no\n");
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &answer);
    }       
}
```

Comment: if you expect your loop to return to the `printf("Enter a number: \n")`-part, please note that this part is outside of the loop. What do you actually observe and what do you expect?

Comment: If you want to skip leading white-space before a character, use a format string with a space. As in `" %c"`. Also note that with your loop condition, anything but a lower-case `'n'` would continue the loop, not only `'y'`.

Comment: And this is also a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Step through the code line by line in a debugger, checking the values of all variables (and save the result from `getchar` in a dummy variable so you can check that too).

Comment: I just tested your code and it has the expected behaviour if you like to stop when you write 'n' and continue when you write 'y' so I don't see your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made few corrections in your program.

1. It was difficult to understand what your program does. I have made your program more readable and modular by defining a separate re-usable function for `factorial`.
2. It makes more sense to ask user again for the number if user has entered `'y'`. So, I have moved required code.
3. I don't recommend mix use of `scanf` and `getchar` in the program. So, we can just use `scanf` for the program. The `scanf()` function removes whitespace automatically before trying to parse conversions other than characters. The character formats (primarily %c; also scan sets %[…] — and %n) are the exception; they don't remove whitespace.

Use " %c" with a `leading blank` to skip optional white space. Do not use a trailing blank in a scanf() format string.

Note that this still doesn't consume any trailing whitespace left in the input stream, not even to the end of a line, so beware of that if also using getchar() or fgets() on the same input stream. We're just getting scanf to skip over whitespace before conversions, like it does for %d and other non-character conversions.

```
#include <stdio.h>


unsigned long factorial(unsigned long num)
{
    unsigned long mult = 1;
    unsigned long k = 1;
    while (k <= num) {
        mult *= k;
        k++;
    }

    return mult;
}

int main(void)
{
    char answer = 'y';

    do {
        int num = 0;
        printf("Enter a number: \n");
        scanf(" %d", &num);


        unsigned long mult = factorial(num);
        printf("%d! = %lu\n", num, mult);

        printf("Would you like to try another number? \n");
        printf("Enter: y for yes | n for no\n");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

    } while (answer != 'n');  

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    getchar(); // takes the user input but assigns it nowhere
    scanf("%c", &answer); // reads newline, aborts while loop
```

Use `c = getchar();` and omit the `scanf`.

Also note that a more idiomatic way of doing this would be with a `do-while` loop instead.

Comment: In the first iteration that will read the newline left over from the first call to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and the loop continues: it does not re-ask for the number because that part is outside the loop. Move it inside. Also notice that your code continues executing even when pressing any other key rather than `n`.

This is a one way to do it starting from your code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
            char answer = 'y';
            int num = 0;

            while(answer != 'n')
            {
                    printf("Enter a number: \n");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    int mult = 1;
                    int k = 1;
                    while (k <= num)
                    {
                            mult *= k;
                            k++;
                    }
                    printf("%d! = %d\n", num, mult);

                    printf("Would you like to try another number? \n");
                    printf("Enter: any key for  yes | n for no\n");
                    getchar();
                    scanf("%c", &answer);
            }
    }
```